# How do I use Item IDs in Commands?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

To use the ID part in these hacks the number 5 will make it green, but 2 will make it orange and others.

```
/setblock ~~~ wool 5 
/setblock ~~~ wool 2
/setblock ~~~ wool 7
/setblock ~~~ wool 8
```

The number at the end will make the wool a different colour than white.

Answer (score 1):

To use the ID part in commands, the number 5 will make it green, but 2 will make it orange and others.

```
/setblock ~~~ wool 5 
/setblock ~~~ wool 2
/setblock ~~~ wool 7
/setblock ~~~ wool 8
```

The number at the end will make the wool a different color than white.

Comment: These are no longer called Block IDs (in fact, 'wool' in your case is the Block ID), and the numbers following them are (besides the quantity) now called [Data Values](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Data_values) or "Damage Values" (from their use in weapons/tools)